# Problems with float: it does not return the fraction

Tags: java, android

I am puzzled that a float does not return the fraction. The code:

```
float max_stops;
int maxBellows = 330;
int lensFocal = 135;
max_stops =  (maxBellows / lensFocal );
```

returns 2.0 instead of 2.44.

Can you pls help me get this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cast `maxBellows` and `lensFocal` to float. Since they're both ints, `maxBellows / lensFocal` returns an int, which then gets cast to float when it's assigned to `max_stops`. At least one of `maxBellows` and `lensFocal` should be cast to a float.

Comment: @koenbro You can accept this as an answer :) `Thanks, this solved it! `

Answer (score 3):

an int divided by an int yields an int.

Make one of the operands a float, e.g.

```
max_stops =  ((float)maxBellows / lensFocal );
```

Answer (score 2):

The / operator for two ints returns an int.
You need to divide by 135.0 or cast the variables to float or whatever

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with `float` but with `int` - this `maxBellows / lensFocal` is a division of two `int` values, which means it will have an `int` result, no matter whether that result is then put into a `float` variable. To get a `float` result, you have to cast one of the operands to `float` before the calculation:

```
max_stops =  maxBellows / (float)lensFocal;
```

Answer (score 2):

try these :

```
max_stops =  ((float)maxBellows / lensFocal );

or

max_stops =  (maxBellows / (float) lensFocal );
```